# Use of undeclared type 'QLPreviewControllerDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift3, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I would like to implement QuickLook framework in swift 4 to preview Documents or PDF, but getting this issue, while this is working in Objective C. had tried a lot, Could someone please help. I am not even getting any sample anywhere QuickLook framework with swift 4.

[image]

Comment: show your code..

Comment: @MilanNosáľ i have updated screenshot of code.

Comment: What is the name of your project? `QuickLook` ?

Comment: @pkc456 is this matter? QuickLook is a framework by Apple for previewing documents.

Comment: As Warning says file is part of module quicklook. So there might be chances of overriding that file is not getting th framework path

Comment: So what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You did not import the module "QuickLook" (see the warning you got) because you're presumably in a target named "QuickLook". Since you did not import QuickLook, QLPreviewControllerDataSource was not imported. Rename your target and you should be all set.